# How can we uniform all PDF paper sizes

Tags: linux, pdf, utility

What utility, How's its syntax usage, which can uniform all PDF paper sizes on Linux the simplest way, preferably by CLI?

Answer (score 1):

You could give [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) a try; it is a versatile tool for working with PDF files.

Something like this might work for you:

```
gs -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dPDFFitPage input.pdf ...
```

If the paper size you want is not on the list of [known paper sizes](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.25/Use.htm#Known_paper_sizes), you can give a custom paper size in points (1/72ths of an inch) by `-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS` and `-dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS`.